# FileNotFoundException SQLite

Tags: c#, revit

I am trying to use a SQLite in a Revit App but got the error shown in the image.
the dll is referenced and I put it in the directory but it didn't work.
What is the possible reason?
[image]

Comment: Mind if i ask , are you using crack version of `Revit` ?do you have the license file of it or not ?

Comment: Yes,  I have the full license.

Answer (score 0):

[SQLite for .net have many versions](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki). I do not know which version do you use, but for the Revit, which is only 64bit, I recommend to use this one:

[sqlite-netFx45-binary-x64-2012-1.0.108.0.zip](http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.108.0/sqlite-netFx45-binary-x64-2012-1.0.108.0.zip).

For this version, two dlls files (at least) need to be put in the app directory:
System.Data.SQLite.dll and SQLite.Interop.dll